# What is TARGET_API_MAC_CARBON?

Tags: macos-carbon

I am new to Objective-C and OS X development. I see this in some code I'm trying to get to work:

```
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>

#if ! TARGET_API_MAC_CARBON

#include <OSA.h>
#include <AppleScript.h>
#include <Gestalt.h>

#endif

#include <string.h>
```

when is TARGET_API_MAC_CARBON defined? Wikipedia says carbon is the old API. I don't see a "TARGET_API_MAC_COCOA" or anything. I only need the code to work on Mac OS X 10.9.

Answer (score 1):

Carbon should be defined if you're linking the Carbon framework (which you're almost certainly not doing).  It's the legacy technology that was used to bridge MacOS apps between "Classic MacOS" (i.e. MacOS 7, 8, 9) and today's MacOS 10.X releases.

That said, I have to wonder about the code you're trying to link in.  How old is it?  [Gestalt, for example, is pretty fully deprecated at this point](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/reference/Gestalt_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000036-CH202-SW1).

Comment: doesn't seem too old: https://github.com/reinerp/haskell-AppleScript/tree/master/cbits

Comment: maybe I should make a new question, but can you point me to a first step to writing a hello world program in which some C code calls AppleScript and processes its result?

Comment: Cocoa has a [handy "`NSApplescript`" class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAppleScript_Class/Reference/Reference.html) but if you want to do Applescript from pure C, you'll likely have to call "`system`" from your C code, making use of the shell's ["`osascript`" tool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osascript.1.html) (in other words, the code won't be super neat or elegant).

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about just using the shell, but I've noticed  some latency. Maybe I can keep osascript running in a process as a repl or something? The context is I want to input text and move the mouse, given voice commands, where the faster the better. hence bindings.